# Extract fax number or phone from a single string?

Tags: java, android

working on OCR project on android, after scanning the text format 
out of string in one condition are

```
Tel:+91 345677890 Fax: +91 80 222767000
```

in  need to extract only phone number and fax number.

In Second example

```
xyaz@mail.com ,Fax:+91 80 222767000
```

I need to separate the both fax, tel and email into a variables

Did this but unable to find the solution

```
String cellfound="Tel:+91 345677890 Fax: +91 80 222767000 xyaz@mail.com";
Pattern cellp1= Pattern.compile(".*\\b(Mobile|M|M )\\b.*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher cellm1 = cellp1.matcher(cellnumber);
if (cellm1.matches()) {
    cellfound=cellm1.group();
    System.out.println("\nbefore cell found "+cellfound);
    cellfound=cellfound.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ");
    System.out.println("\nfinal cell found from pattern :"+cellfound);
}
```

Comment: use String.subString() method to seperate data

Comment: Sounds like a job for regex.

Comment: Use regex as phone numbers should be a regular expressions.

Comment: its a one string contains "Tel:+91 345677890 Fax: +91 80 222767000  xyaz@mail.com"

Comment: @vbijoor Have you tried *anything* in order to solve it yourself? It should be fairly easy with regex, just read a tutorial and give it a try.

Comment: @vbijoor and you hit it - nobody will even try to read that

Comment: need the solution kindly  provide the solution

Comment: edit the question and add the code, DON'T put it in comments!

Comment: @vbijoor - Done. Answered. Would have done it before if you had shown what you have tried when posting your question

Comment: @vbijoor Have you solved your problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s ="Tel:+91 345677890 Fax: +91 80 222767000";
    String[] arr = s.split("[a-zA-Z:]+\\s*");
    for (String str : arr){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    String s2 = "xyaz@mail.com ,Fax:+91 80 222767000";
    arr = s2.split(",\\w+:");
    for (String str : arr){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
<empty String here> // ignore this value
+91 345677890 
+91 80 222767000
xyaz@mail.com 
+91 80 222767000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?<=Tel[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)|(?<=Fax[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)|(?<=\\s)(\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}\\b)
```

*Explanation:*

`(?<=Tel[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)` matches *numbers* and *spaces* group that is preceded by *"Tel:"* -> this captures the tel number.

`(?<=Fax[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)` matches *numbers* and *spaces* group that is preceded by *"Fax:"* -> this captures the fax number

And the last one `(?<=\\s)(\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}\\b)` is the email regex that is preceded by a space.

As you can see, *Tel* and *Fax* has almost the same regex. We can combine it into one, but I want to separate it for a clearer result.

Here is the sample code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String test = "Tel:+91 345677890 Fax: +91 80 222767000 xyaz@mail.com";

        String regex = "(?<=Tel[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)|" // this captures the tel number
                + "(?<=Fax[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)|" // this captures the fax number
                + "(?<=\\s)(\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}\\b)"; // this captures the email string

        // Remember the CASE_INSENSITIVE option
        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher m = re.matcher(test);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0).trim());
        }
     }
}
```

Expected result is like:

```
+91 345677890                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+91 80 222767000                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
xyaz@mail.com
```