# Get Phone Number Label from String

Tags: ios, swift

How to get the phone number Label like Home, Work, Mobile, Fax, etc from string.
For example below is the string and one of the number i.e (91) 98203 88212 is mobile. So how to detect that.

```
Phone: (91-22) 6641 1234
Direct: (91-22) 6691 8972
Fax: (91-22) 6691 1455
Mobile: (91) 98203 88212
```

Just like how business card OCR apps works. What logic is used behind to detect the phone number label?

Comment: try regex maybe?

Comment: @N.Ivanov Regex only tells whether is valid number or not. Not the type like Fax, Mobile, Home.

Comment: @Nitesh you use regex to extract information, it is a very common use

Comment: @Scriptable can you please share one.

Comment: Checkout this article: http://nshipster.com/nsregularexpression/

Comment: Can someone help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904008/extract-fax-number-or-phone-from-a-single-string . I have tried regex from that but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If you have **CNContact** object then you can get these easily.

```
for item in personContact.phoneNumbers {
        if let label = item.label{
            let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: label)
//You will get your label here
            print(localizedLabel)
        }else{
            print(item.value.stringValue)
        }
    }
```

Or if you have only String values then can use:

```
 let contacts = ["Phone: (91-22) 6641 1234",
    "Direct: (91-22) 6691 8972",
    "Fax: (91-22) 6691 1455",
    "Mobile: (91) 98203 88212"]
    for contact in contacts{
        let contactParts = contact.components(separatedBy: ":")
        print(contactParts[0])
    }
```